# Create Shell Script to Find Shell Scripts in Folder and Execute Them

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have complex folder structure under one main folder. The folder where shell script can be is max 3 levels deep.

I want to write a shell script which will scan through all folders, find any file ending in .sh and execute the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try something?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash

all_files=` find Testdir -name "*.sh" -type f`

for file in $all_files
do
        bash $file
done
```

The find command finds all the file names that ends with .sh extension recursively and the output is stored in a variable.
Using that variable, the for loop executes all the files one by one.

> Note :
>          Make sure to have the if condition inside the for loop to check the file name is not a current executing script file. Because, if you
>   execute that file, it will get into infinity. It again and again
>   executes infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#! /bin/bash
find /mainfolder -name '*.sh' > /home/dumm.txt
while read abc
do
$abc
done < <(cut -f1 /home/dumm.txt)
```

Explanation:

- The find command searches and lists the (full) path for file names that end with '.sh' under your main folder
- The list is stored in a file
- Each row of this file is then executed in the while loop

Comment: Is the find command stores the file names with comma in dumm.txt file ?

Comment: Oops. no need of the delimiter (-d',') in 'cut'. My mistake while copying from a similar script of mine. It'll work though. 

Modified now!!

Comment: Did you really need a temporary file ?

Comment: In fact, I didn't see your answer before I posted mine. This was a script I used for a similar functionality and quoted it here.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15054680)

Comment: @Ferrybig Thanks!!! Will surely follow it!!